# Elasticsearch nested-range query must_not

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, date-range

I've looking for this for a while in google & stack. In elastic search index we have a nested field that contains several dates representing dare range, like this:

```
"plazos" : [
        {
          "id" : 1,
          "fechainicio" : "01/04/2023",
          "fechafin" : "31/04/2023"
        },
        {
          "id" : 2,
          "fechainicio" : "09/11/2023",
          "fechafin" : "29/11/2023"
        }
      ]
```

We could have more than 2 elements in nested. If an element is IN date today has to be between `fechainicio` and `fechafin` in ONE OR MORE ELEMENTS in nested `plazos`, that works fine as:

```
"bool" : {
"must" : [
  {
    "range" : {
      "plazos.fechainicio" : {
        "from" : null,
        "to" : "19/04/2023",
        "include_lower" : true,
        "include_upper" : true,
        "boost" : 1.0
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "range" : {
      "plazos.fechafin" : {
        "from" : "19/04/2023",
        "to" : null,
        "include_lower" : true,
        "include_upper" : true,
        "boost" : 1.0
      }
    }
  }
],
"adjust_pure_negative" : true,
"boost" : 1.0
```

because It matches element `"id":1`

The problem is if an element is OUT OF DATE today has to be IN NONE elemets. I have tried the same  request but with `must_not` but as ONE of the elements (`"id":2`) is OUT OF DATE the same document matches IN DATE and OUT OF DATE. How can I say "to be OUT OF DATE you have to be OUT OF DATE in all elements in `plazos` nested elements. `plazos` can have more than 2 elements.

Thanks in advance
best regards

EDIT
due to privacy &stuff like that I can share few informatio. I had share an example of `plazos` and a the range query only. I think I can share `plazos` mapping but I think is the limit I can share:

```
"plazos" : {
        "type" : "nested",
        "properties" : {
          "fechafin" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "dd/MM/yyyy"
          },
          "fechainicio" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "dd/MM/yyyy"
          },
          "id" : {
            "type" : "integer",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "masinformacion" : {
            "type" : "keyword",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: Can you share the mapping of the index

Answer (score 0):

Finaly got it:

```
"bool" : {
    
    "must_not" : [
      {
        "range" : {
          "plazos.fechainicio" : {
            "from" : "19/04/2023",
            "to" : null,
            "include_lower" : true,
            "include_upper" : true,
            "boost" : 1.0
            
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "range" : {
          "plazos.fechafin" : {
            "from" : null,
            "to" : "19/04/2023",
            "include_lower" : true,
            "include_upper" : true,
            "boost" : 1.0
            
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "should": [
      {
        "range": {
          "plazos.fechainicio" : {
            "from" : null,
            "to" : "19/04/2023",
            "include_lower" : false,
            "include_upper" : false,
            "boost" : 1.0
            
          }
        }
        
      },
      {
      "range": {
          "plazos.fechafin" : {
            "from" : "19/04/2023",
            "to" : null,
            "include_lower" : false,
            "include_upper" : false,
            "boost" : 1.0
            
          }
        }
      }
    ], 
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0,
    "minimum_should_match": 2
    
    
  }
```

Hope this could help!